# Combination of Node.JS(+ Socket.io) and PHP, what about users and changing Socket ID's

Tags: php, node.js, authentication, socket.io

I have been playing around with Node.js for two days now, I am slowly understanding how it works. I have checked multiple threads and posts now but I seem to either misunderstanding them or the way I am thinking about this application is completely wrong.

My application is mainly based on PHP and uses Node.js as a notifications system.
I first wanted to this solely in Node.js but I am more familiar with PHP so that is why I only want to use Node.js as a notifications system.

I do not have any real code to show as I have been mainly playing around and see all what Node can do and so far it seems to be the thing I need, there is one thing I just can't figure out or seem to mis understand. So far I figured out how to send data between the user and the server and used socket.io for this.

So, what if I have a user, which is registered and logs-in on my application. He then has a socket id from socket.io, but when the user leaves my application and comes back the next day his socket ID is changed because it seems to change on every connection. I need to have my users somehow always have the same socket ID or something else which tells my node.js server that it should only send data to one specific user or multiple users. Also, as the socketid seems to change on every request it is even changed when the user visits a different page so I don't ever seem to know which user is what.

I am a little confused and the flow of working with both PHP and Node.js is still a little mystery to me so I hope my question is clear. I dont want to be depending on many modules as I find all these different modules kind of confusing for a beginner like me.

Comment: do you share "sessions" between PHP and Node.JS ?

Comment: No, have not thought about that. Would it be a reasonable solution? Setting a session in php a D transfering it to node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as PHP-Node.js are using sessions stored somewhere else other than flag file sessions let's say a cache service or a database mysql or nosql ..

you can use the "same flat file" sessions thought cache or database could be make your application "more"
of course there are additional practises of allowing authenticated users to try to connect by controlling **when** to render the javascript code that holds the information to connect to socket.io server, where an additional list is stored in memory of all connected having information like username/log/timestamps/session variables/etc..

Comment: Is this the only way to do it? It seems so unlogical. I did manage to do it this way though, by saving all users and their sockets in an array on the server side. But it somehow feels dirty.

Comment: it not "dirty" its a way of tracking user connected to websocket server, thats how games,chats do it and has worked pretty well so far

Comment: Okay, but when an existing user opens a new window a new socket is created, which you then have to save in an array containing all sockets from a user. I am not saying it wouldn't work, it's just that in my opinion there should be a cleaner way of achieving this by somehow using the same socket (which does not seem to be possible).

Comment: yes there are possibilities of a user opening up like 100 windows which means 100 connection requests, no matter what application (game/chat/etc) this should be handled by server, which assigns a unique ID to each client, of course you can use SESSIONS to authenticate clients trying to connect and disconnect them if it sees that a client with same credentials is already connected .. i'll not say there is or isn't a cleaner way it really depends on how you want your application to handle it ..

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I always assumed this to be handles automatically